# Subject + sound + Adjective

Tags: verbs, sounds

I called after him, worried that I might have sounded ungrateful.

Unlike 'It sounds [Adjective].', if a person subject comes instead of 'it', what does the verb 'sound' mean?
I'm not sure for the above sentence, but it looks to me as if 'worried that I might have made words that he could have mistaken as ungrateful.' or 'worried that the words what I made might have sounded ungrateful to him.'.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question.  It illustrates the sometimes perplexing flexibility of English.  *Oxford Dictionaries* online provides a host of example of this usage.  I have used most of them, so that the usage can settle in.

The pattern is for the verb (used intransitively) to be followed by an adjectival complement.

> Convey a specified impression when heard.
> with complement

- ‘My heart sank when I heard how happy she sounded.’
- ‘This time she said it louder, sounding genuinely confused.’
- ‘I thought entirely out loud and probably sounded quite crazy.’
- ‘I record phrases that I use often and playback to hear how I may sound to others when I say them.’
- ‘She didn't sound that pleased to hear from him.’
- ‘I had some difficulty deciding on a starter as they all sounded so tempting.’
- ‘I like that he always sounds happy to hear from me, even for a short call about nothing.’

This type of usage is common with verbs of *sensation*:

> To look:  *The house looks dirty/stylish*; *Your draft proposal looks strong*
>
> To feel:  *Your way of saying this feels a bit weak*
>
> To smell:  *Their offer smells fishy to me*.

You could call the formulation as in a sense metaphorical:  using expressions of sensation to represent our understanding of what is said or written.